# Can't access hadoop with Pig embedded

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm using the **pig api 0.12.0** in order to execute pig latin scripts on a remote hadoop server.
To do so, I placed the same `core-site.xml` in my classpath (*src/main/resources*).

This `core-site.xml` is really simple :

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://hadoopserver:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

However, when I run my program, the log say

```
INFO executionengine.HExecutionEngine: Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///
```

Why isn't it connecting to `hdfs://hadoopserver:9000` instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by the fact that the new parameter `fs.defaultFS` isn't supported in this version. As a consequence, your `core-site.xml` should have the following property :

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://hadoopserver:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

You don't have to change that value in your hadoop server though, just in the file readed by the api.